# difficulty opening a file(man page) with funny characters in gVIM

Tags: vim, gvim, unicode

I did man ssh_config>a

from cygwin I generated the file I want to print

`$ man ssh_config >a`

I then opened it in gvim as you see from the screenshot.

I might join many of the lines (vim's J) to stop it from wrapping before the end of the line. But that aside, a problem is the funny characters

The file is UTF-8

```
C:\cygwin\home\user>file a
a; UTF-8 Unicode English text
```

[image]

If I do `:set encoding=utf-8`  then it fixes the funny characters a bit.

There are less squares showing characters that aren't recognized, but there are still unrecognized characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly first specified the proper (UTF-8) encoding. This turned the three-byte sequences into a single Unicode character.

The `ga` command can show you codepoint information about the character under the cursor. For `“Host”`, these are

- U+201C (Left double quotation mark)
- U+201D (Right double quotation mark)

The problem is that your chosen font doesn't have the glyphs for them, so they appear as boxes. (On Windows,) you can fix that e.g. via:

```
:set guifont=Lucida_Console:h10:cANSI
```

#### Additional resources

- the [characterize.vim - Unicode character metadata](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4410) plugin supercharges the mentioned `ga` command with additional information, e.g. the name of the character
- On Linux (vs. the Cygwin you've used), the `man` output may contain *reverse linefeeds* (which on mechanical typewriters created special effects like bold or underline by stepping back and writing yet another character over the printed one); you can filter those away by piping the `man` output through `col -b` (whose man page has additional info about this).

Comment: thanks, is there also a way to show the hex for a character rather than the codepoint e.g. when I have like the funny left quote character, unicode code point of 201C  I understand and see from xxd and this site, that the stored hex of that is quite different it is E2 80 9C http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128    How can I get gVIM to show me the E2 80 9C in the status bar.. when I have my cursor over a character i'd like to know the hex for?  I can do the 'ga' command and it shows me 201C for the funny left quote, but i'd like it to show the stored hex E2 80 9C

Comment: That's `g8` for you; it's mentioned in the excellent `:help` right below the `ga` command.

Comment: setting to that font worked. But I was wondering what font gvim defaults to? I just started a fresh vim and did `:set guifont?` but just got the response of `guifont=`

Comment: Looks like `Fixedsys`; there aren't so many fixed-width font available by default.